# NgModel not always updating text input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I'm working on a scenario where I want the `ngModel` to get update based on certain conditions

Template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>val:</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="someVal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
</mat-form-field>
```

Component:

```
someVal: number = 10;
onChange(val: number):void {
  if(val > 10){
    this.someVal = 0;
  }
}
```

On the first attempt to change the value to something greater than 10, the view updates. But subsequent changes don't. What causes this behavior and how does one work around this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I did this for now.

```
private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef

public someVal: number = 10;
onChange(val: number):void {
  if(val > 10){
    this.someVal = null;
    this._cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.someVal = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this ...

```
[(ngModel)]="someVal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

do this ...

```
[ngModel]="someVal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"

onChange(val: number):void {
  if(val > 10) val = 0;
  this.someVal = val;
}
```

Comment: This made no difference. Value still doesn't display `0` after the second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Add name property.

```
<input matInput name="val" [(ngModel)]="someVal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```